# How to use Shared Component with 2 React Native Apps

Tags: import, react-native, components

I need to use shared components from outside of my ReactNative Project

example

- ReactNatvieProject1

  - src

    - app.js (here i need to import TestContainer from '../../Shared/TestComponent')
- ReactNativeProject2

  - src

    - app.js (here i need to import TestContainer from '../../Shared/TestComponent')
- Shared

  - TestComponent

I need to use the TestComponent in each of React Native Project
how can i accomplish that

thanks !

Comment: Create a npm module for your shared component and include it in your `package.json` in your two RN projects

Comment: how do i include it on the package.json ?